# UI-route nested views and resolve not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, android-contentresolver

I have a problem with resolve and my nested view is not loading because ot that. I don't see where is the problem. This was working with ng-route.

Here is my situation. We should see "View3" text bellow other tow. If you remove the resolve it will work.

[http://plnkr.co/edit/p483wWVSp30LGiQMuk1r?p=preview][1]

```
[1]: http://plnkr.co/edit/p483wWVSp30LGiQMuk1r?p=preview
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my State with Resolve. The problem is that i used $route as parameter. $route is averrable for ng-route module.

```
.state('test.subs.quest', {
  url: '/:bob',
  views: {
    'quest@test': {
      template: "View3",
      controller: function($stateParams) {
        console.log($stateParams);
      }
    },
  },
  resolve: {
    Questions: function(Questionnaire, $route) {
      console.log('any body here  ?');
      return Questionnaire.Get($route.current.params.slug);
    }
  }

});
```

and it should be like this:

```
 .state('categories.category.questionnaire', {
    url: '/:slug',
    views:{
        "main@":{
            template: '<div compilehtml="html"></div>',
            controller: 'QuestionnaireController',
        }
    },
    resolve: {
        Questions: function(Questionnaire, $stateParams ) {
            return Questionnaire.Get($stateParams.slug); 
        }
    }
})
```